# Touch events in Android

Tags: android, button, touch

I have a button widget. I want to play sound when the button is pressed and when the user releases the button (takes his finger off the button) the audio playback should be stopped. I have used the following code but it doesn't work.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
    int action = me.getAction();
    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        playSound();
    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        stopSound();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How did you register the touch listener?

Comment: button.setOnTouchListener(l);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `stopSound()` being called? I think you need to return true in the `action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` block to tell the system that you handled the event.